# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement bootstrapping myself

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying to bootstrap myself up on the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace in order to solve another issue I'm having. In net i want to toggle the "ChangePasswordOnNextLogon" flag in ad and this namespace made it look easy.

So I tried using it with the same users and passwords that I use to login using the `AdMembershipProvider`.

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "10.1.XXX.XXX", "DC=XXXXXXXX,DC=ORG",
                        ContextOptions.SimpleBind, AUserThatWorks, APasswordThatWorks);

UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = 
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, AdUserName);

// we need to see if they can authenticate before changing password,so we have to turn this off manually. - EWB
oUserPrincipal.RefreshExpiredPassword();

bool b = oPrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials( AdUserName, AdPassword );

if (!b)
   oUserPrincipal.ExpirePasswordNow();

return b;
```

But when it gets to `FindByIdentity` I get a "bad user or password" error.

Since the user works elsewhere, I figure it's gotta be one of the other parameters to get principal context. Anyone got any Hints for me? I tried putting LDAP infront of the URL but then it failed to connect. I'm stumped.

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying your PrincipalContext line:

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "XXXXXX.org", AUserThatWorks, PasswordThatWorks);
```

This assumes your domain is XXXXXXX.org. You can also try putting your domain in front of your username: "XXXXXX.org\username".